# capture headers via lua nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, http-headers, nginx-config

I want to capture only some headers which contains word "foo". I used for it [lua nginx module](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/lua/)
My code

```
    location /lua_test {

        content_by_lua_block {
            local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
            for k, v in pairs(h) do
                if k == k:match("([%w].Foo.*):(.+)") then
                    ngx.header[k] = v
                end
            end
            ngx.say('headers with Foo are captured');
        }

    }
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.
Sorry, I'm newbie to Lua and nginx. Thanks for any help

Comment: ah sorry, fixed it. Replaced string from
`if k == k:match("([%w].Foo.*):(.+)") then`
to
`if k == k:match("([%w].Foo.*)") then`
and it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be need to look in the values:

```
        local h = ngx.req.get_headers()
        for k, v in pairs(h) do
            if v:find("foo") then -- equivalent v:match("foo") 
                ngx.header[k] = v
            end
        end
```

or do you have your own keys: `if k:find("foo") then`